# Tensorflow/AI Cloud Platform: HyperTune trials failed to report the hyperparameter tuning metric

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform

I'm using the `tf.estimator` API with TensorFlow 2.1 on Google AI Platform to build a DNN Regressor. To use AI Platform Training hyperparameter tuning, I followed [Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-hyperparameter-tuning).
I used the following configuration parameters:

config.yaml:

```
trainingInput:
    scaleTier: BASIC
    hyperparameters:
        goal: MINIMIZE
        maxTrials: 2
        maxParallelTrials: 2
        hyperparameterMetricTag: rmse
        enableTrialEarlyStopping: True
        params:
        - parameterName: batch_size
          type: DISCRETE
          discreteValues:
          - 100
          - 200
          - 300
        - parameterName: lr
          type: DOUBLE
          minValue: 0.0001
          maxValue: 0.1
          scaleType: UNIT_LOG_SCALE
```

And to add the metric to my summary, I used the following code for my DNNRegressor:

```
def rmse(labels, predictions):
    pred_values = predictions['predictions']
    rmse = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(name='root_mean_squared_error')
    rmse.update_state(labels, pred_values)
    return {'rmse': rmse}

def train_and_evaluate(hparams):
    ...
    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
                       model_dir = output_dir,
                       feature_columns = get_cols(),
                       hidden_units = [max(2, int(FIRST_LAYER_SIZE * SCALE_FACTOR ** i))
                        for i in range(NUM_LAYERS)],
                       optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
                       config = run_config)
    estimator = tf.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, rmse)
```

According to Google's documentation, the `add_metric` function creates a new estimator with the metric specified, which is then used as the hyperparameter metric. However, the AI Platform Training service doesn't recognise this metric:
[Job details on AI Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwzq1.png)

On running the code locally, the rmse metric does get outputted in the logs.
So, **how do I make the metric available to the Training job on AI Platform using Estimators?**

Additionally, there is an option of reporting the metrics through the `cloudml-hypertune` Python package. But it requires the value of the metric as one of the input arguments. **How do I extract the metric from `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` function** (since that's the function I use to train/evaluate my estimator) to input into the `report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric` function?

```
hpt = hypertune.HyperTune()
hpt.report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric(
    hyperparameter_metric_tag='rmse',
    metric_value=??,
    global_step=1000
)
```

ETA: [Logs show no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSfPw.png). It says that the job completed successfully even though it fails.

Comment: Could you share some log?, within your image there is "View logs" link, there you can found more information about why is failing.

Comment: @MarianaAngeles I have attached a screenshot of the logs in the edit.  They show no errors so they aren't of much help here.

Comment: Not sure if this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804758/10409068) could help  for the question about *cloudml-hypertune*, regarding the *add_metric* I suggest you to open a support case to delve into the issue, due to no errors in the logs they could inspect your project to determine the root cause of the issue.